# How can I back up and restore data from a Riak cluster?

Tags: riak

How can I back up and restore data from a Riak cluster? What commands do I need to run?

Answer (score 4):

First, on each machine, you need to know a valid node name and the Erlang cookie value.

You can find out what nodes you have by running `riak-admin status | grep 'nodename'`

You can find the cookie name in `vm.args`. For me, this file was located in `/usr/local/riak/etc/`. There should be a line like "-setcookie foo`. The default value is 'riak'.

On the machine where you want to do the backup, run (from [the docs](http://wiki.basho.com/Command-Line-Tools---riak-admin.html)):

```
sudo riak-admin backup <node> <cookie> <filename> [[node|all]]
```

For example:

```
sudo riak-admin backup rk1@192.168.10.201 MyCookieVal /home/me/riak-backup-01-11-2012.dat all
```

(The `.dat` file extension is arbitrary.)

Note that you can run this command remotely if the machine you're running it from has `riak-admin` available.

On the machine where you want to do the restore, run (from [the docs](http://wiki.basho.com/Command-Line-Tools---riak-admin.html)):

```
riak-admin restore <node> <cookie> <filename>
```

For example:

```
riak-admin restore riak@127.0.0.1 MyCookieVal ~/riak-production-backup-01-11-2012.dat
```

Comment: Just a note on file permissions, check this thread too http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2010-May/001162.html !

Comment: Just a note from 2021 - `riak-admin backup` is deprecated in new Riak KV versions and won't work anymore, thus Riak remains with NO valid backup method.